# Meaning of "quarter" in context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In the sentence

> Onlookers worried that the virus could spread like wildfire through India's slums, where residents live in cramped **quarters** and basic sanitation often isn't available. ([cnn.com](https://edition.cnn.com/2020/04/28/india/india-coronavirus-outbreak-explained-intl-hnk/index.html))

I understand *quarters* is referring to residences, but does the word imply any additional meaning? For instance, should we assume each of those houses consists of a single room?

I've seen the expression *cramped quarters* referring to other kinds of confined spaces besides houses, like cages, small cars and space craft chambers. But when it comes to houses, does it always mean single-room houses?

Another question: who are the **onlookers** here? Are they just residents who witness the problem or are they authorities, specialists sharing their view from outside the situation?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked it up in a [dictionary](https://www.dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/quarter)? It means *a room or house that has been provided, especially for servants or soldiers and their families, to live in*.

Comment: In the sense of a dwelling place, "quarters" is not particularly precise in its meaning.